# jQuery load with jQuery ui dialog

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui

I want to use pop up that content another asp page.

I use with [jquery.load](https://api.jquery.com/load/) to load the page into the div and with [jquery-ui.dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

My code:

```
<div id="dialog"></div>
```

in page ready:

```
$(function () {
    $('#dialog').load('page.aspx').dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true });
});
```

and in click event

```
$("#btn").click(function()
{
     $("#dialog").dialog('open');
});
```

but when btn is clicked, I get the error

> Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

**EDIT**

If I write

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    $('#dialog').load('page.aspx')
                .dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true })
                .dialog('open');
});
```

it works fine!

But in

```
$("#dialog").dialog('close');
```

I get the same erorr

Comment: @lealam..have you added reference to jquery ?

Comment: yes!!! i added jquery

Comment: check whether you have added jqueryui js.

Comment: @lealam..Are you sure that click event is raised..can you check by just putting a sample alert ?

Comment: be sure about stacking orders of libraries 1.->jquery then 2.-> dialoge/ui library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not define div on a page, but dynamically

i define    `var $dialogRptOpt;`

```
   $(function () {
                 $dialogRptOpt = $('<div></div>').load('page.aspx').dialog({ autoOpen: false,
               title  :$("#txtDialogRpt").val(),
                    modal: true
                }) ;
    });


    $("#btn").click(function()
    {
               $dialogRptOpt.dialog('open');

    });
```